# User class inferred by Authlogic loses respond_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, authlogic

I'm trying to move the authlogic (and other common plugin) configuration from one of my Ruby on Rails applications to a plugin so that I don't have to duplicate the common permissions and authentication features in each application.

The user session class is defined in app/model/user_session.rb for the main application:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  include Limbic::UserSession::Model
end
```

`Limbic::UserSession::Model` is defined in the plugin I'm writing at vendor/plugins/limbic/lib/limbic/user_session/model.rb.

The user class is defined in app/model/user.rb for the main application:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Limbic::User::Model
end
```

When logging in using:

```
  # Logs in User.
  def create
    debugger
    @user_session = user_session_class.new(params[:user_session])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_session.save
  ...
```

I get the following error: undefined method 'respond_to?' for #User:0x7f736477c7f0.

How is it possible for a class instance to even lose respond_to? ?

Comment: I couldn't get the user_session_class method to work, I ended up just hardcoding:

    ::UserSession.authenticate_with ::User
    @user_session = ::UserSession.new(params[:user_session])

`user_session_class' should have returned `::UserSession' using ::User, but user_session_class was using `'UserSession'.constantize', which somehow yielded a different class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using method missing trickery anywhere? [This url](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/07/11/solving-the-method_missing-respond_to-problem/) seems to be talking about a similar problem, perhaps it can help you.

Comment: Yes, I am, but the trickery is still in the main app and it worked.  When I first developed the trickery to bridge ActiveScaffold and Declarative Authorization, I used that url.